# Expire manually a Spring Security Session

Tags: spring, sessionid

I use Spring Security. I don't know how to expire the Spring Security session in a process.

I tried this but it gives a null pointer exception :

```
List<SessionInformation> allSessions;

SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;

// this line returns a null pointer exception
allSessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions("userName", true); 

if (allSessions != null) {
    for (SessionInformation sessionInformation : allSessions) {
        logger.info("Expiring session for user: "
            + username
            + " - "
            + sessionInformation.getSessionId());

        sessionInformation.expireNow();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SessionRegistry` is not a core component of the framework, as it's not required to ensure its normal functionality. Therefore you will need to do some additional configuration to instruct the framework to create and maintain it.

Include this in your Spring Security config within the `<http>` tag:

```
<security:session-management>
    <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="100"/>
</security:session-management>
```

Using the `concurrency-control` tag will result in the `SessionRegistry` being properly wired up with other components of the framework. Since this facility was originally developed to allow configurations where the the number of sessions a user may have is limited, you need to set the `max-sessions` property (otherwise it defaults to 1). Give a sufficiently high number if you don't want this "side effect".

Also, include this in your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Which is needed, so that the `SessionRegistry` gets notified when a user session ends.

After that, don't forget to add `@Autowired` to the declaration of the `SessionRegistry` field in your code, or make sure it is injected in some other way.

Read this [short chapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/session-mgmt.html) of the reference docs for more info on session management in Spring Security.

Comment: Thank you for this nice explaination. But I still get this exception : java.lang.NullPointerException in the same place in this sessionRegistry.getAllSessions("userName", true);

Comment: We can only help you if you share more of your code and configuration. What did you try doing to ensure that the `sessionRegistry` gets actually injected into your class? Is your class instantiated as a spring bean at all? Did you autowire the `sessionRegistry` or used property/constructor injection? What's in your security config? Etc. Please update your questions with relevant details like that.

Comment: `max-sessions` allows multiple concurrent sessions for the same user.How does this relate the question being asked ? From Spring Source Code Description `@param maximumSessions the maximum number of sessions for a user`